# mdply (or similar) a function instead of for loop

Tags: r

I want to generate data from a function iterating over a range of values. The setting is best explained in a small example:

```
myfun <- function(a, b, sims) {
  
  x = 3/a*b 
  y = mean(a*rnorm(sims))
  return(data.frame(x = x, y = y))
}

# Output I want:

d <- data.frame(x = 0, y= 0) 
d[1,] <- myfun(a=4, b=2, sims = 100)
d[2,] <- myfun(a=4, b=3, sims = 100)
d[3,] <- myfun(a=4, b=4, sims = 100)

# --> With a for loop this is easy 

# Using mdply, however, does not work

a <- expand.grid(a=1:3)

d <- plyr::mdply(a, myfun, b=seq(1,100, length=100), sims = 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
data <- expand.grid(a = 1:3, b = 1:100)
result <- do.call(rbind, Map(myfun, data$a, data$b, MoreArgs = list(sims = 100)))
head(result)

#    x           y
#1 3.0 -0.17846248
#2 1.5  0.06837716
#3 1.0  0.01034184
#4 6.0 -0.02898619
#5 3.0  0.10077290
#6 2.0  0.22321839
```

---

A similar way would be if you `Vectorize` `myfun`. `Vectorize` is a wrapper around `mapply`.

```
myfun_vec <- Vectorize(myfun)
t(myfun_vec(data$a, data$b, 100))
```

---

A `purrr` option :

```
result <- purrr::map2_df(data$a, data$b, myfun, sims = 100)
```